# Bootstrap Table Filtering for 2 tables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tab which shows two bootstrap tables (wenzhixin bootstrap tables). One tab shows a table for active equipment and the other in-active equipment.

For now i have done the filtering via 2 different sql statements (one for active equipment and one statement for in-active equipment). But i was wondering if there is a way to do the filtering using the returned result containing all the rows (both active and inactive) for example using the formatter or some other feature which i am not aware of ?

Or is the better solution to filter through sql ?

**How i currently set the table data**

Currently I need to call getActiveEquipment.php and getInactiveEquipment to get the equipment for my active equipment table and in-active equipmenttable. See below how my table for active equipment looks. Id prefere to call getEquipment, which returns ALL equipment and using that result filter the data put into the tables (active equipment -> table 1 , inactive equipment -> table 2)

```
<table id="active_equipment-table" data-toggle="table" data-url="getActiveEquipment.php" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped" data-page-list="[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="type" data-sortable="true">Type</th>
                <th data-field="product" data-sortable="true">Fabrikat</th>
                <th data-field="acquisition" data-sortable="true">Anskaffelsesår</th> 
                <th data-field="calibration_interval" data-sortable="true">Eftersynsinterval</th> 
                <th data-field="equipment_no" data-sortable="true">Instrument nr.</th>
                <th data-field="inspection_date" data-sortable="true">Seneste eftersyn</th> 
                <th data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: Add your code please, no one will help you unless you add all of the relevant code!

Comment: there is no code except the current code for setting data for my bootstrap table. I am not expecting a coded solution but requesting alternatives for filtering data with some, for me, unknown feature of the bootstrap table like f.ex. data-formatter or?

Comment: You need to add your current HTML, SQL and any other code that you currently have, otherwise it extremely difficult to even begin to make a suggestion for a solution.

Comment: @Schmalzy: done though not very interesting ;)

Comment: it is interesting, because now we know how you are initializing the table and that you are using PHP.... very helpful information

Comment: @Schmalzy: your right wasnt thinking clear ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought this might need my own answer.

Did not find any other alternative for filtering the received data before binding it to my data property of my tables.

So the solution was simply to create the getEquipment.php which is responsible for calling my API and fetch the data, and supply it with an argument for active as such.

getEquipment?active=1 and getEquipment?active=0

The filtering will then be handled in my database handler of my API